# How do I write ASCII files from internet URL's directly into Stata?

Tags: ascii, stata

I'm trying to write a set of files (ex. https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/files/reports-statements/mts/mts1103.txt) into Stata.

Because I want a number of months and years from the source website (https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/reports-statements/mts/previous.html) I was hoping I could write it directly from each URL into Stata using a for loop and then clear/append them together as I've done many times before. (Don't want to download them all independently).

```
Something like this:
foreach yr in 04 05 06 07 08 09 {
    foreach month in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 {
        insheet using "https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/files/reports-statements/mts/mts`month'03.txt", clear
    }
}
```

Would something like this be possible? What would I need to do to make this work with a ASCII file?

Comment: The year doesn't appear inside your loop.

Comment: The commands work in so far as Stata will read these files. They need major surgery before they would be useful as datasets.

Answer (score 1):

The code should work (do note Nick Cox's comment on the year local). I would personally recommend that you copy the files to your local drive first, because you cannot trust that those files will remain available forever.

You can use Stata's copy command to do that.

This has the additional advantage that you split the download and parsing parts - maybe insheet fails to handle the particular format of one file and causes issues. In general, modular code is almost always a good idea.

Don't forget to include a save-command in the loop, or all your hard work will be for nothing (been there).